# Internal Google Font CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

We are looking to place the [Google Font for Open Sans](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans) within the `<head>` tag rather than insert it onto the page using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" media="all">`.

**What is the correct way to insert this into the `<head>` tag of the page?**

We tried the following, but cannot find whether or not this is correct.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFUZ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWZ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVp0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWp0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFW50bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0b.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/css2.css">
</head>
<body>
  ... some body ...
</body>
</html>
```

Within the `css1.css`, we do the following:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open sans';
}
```

Comment: For future reference, this would be *internal* rather than *inline*. *Internal* CSS is in the `head` of the HTML file. *Inline* CSS is directly attached to a specific element in the HTML file, such as `<div style=" ">`.

Comment: @Nick thanks for the explanation. The question has been updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you actually apply the Style by using e.G.

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

you will see that the new font is applied to the body. So it is working.
Cf. the Mozilla Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWJ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFUZ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWZ0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVp0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFWp0bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFW50bbck.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFVZ0b.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  ... some body ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did update the question with more details. It looks like similar to what you have shown above. Is it correct to say that you think we should be able to get this done with your answer as long as the `font-family: 'Open sans';` as long as it is defined `after` the `<style>` tag?

Comment: Yes. In fact, you could declare it at the top of your css1.css aswell

Comment: @usernameabc Also, if you want to use internal styling, you have to declare the font-family rule inside the style-tag.

Comment: so if i understand you correctly, if i define the `font-family: 'Open Sans'` inside of the `css1.css` file, it is incorrect? It has to be within the same `<style>` tag where the `internal Google Font CSS` is placed in?

Comment: @usernameabc No. The only constraint is that the `@font-face` declaration should come before using `font-family`. It doesn't matter if it's in two different style tags or even two different files.